# How do i get the last 2 numbers from a url into a variable using javascript

Tags: javascript

Example url:

> www.example.com/example/createnew/#47

or

> www.example.com/example/createnew/#5462

I want to put the number behind the  '#' in a variable. but the size of the number can change.

how do i do this?

(without jquery or any other library)

Comment: `'www.example.com/example/createnew/#5462'.split('#')[1]`

Comment: i dont want to use Jquery

Comment: that's not jquery, it's normal javascript and faster than regex. Probably the best solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**

```js
var res = 'www.example.com/example/createnew/#5462'.split('#')[1],
  res1 = 'www.example.com/example/createnew/#47'.split('#')[1];
document.write(res + '<br>' + res1);
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what i needed ;_)

Comment: @wormen22 : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'www.example.com/example/createnew/#5462';
var num = parseInt(url.match(/\d+$/)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var val = "www.example.com/example/createnew/#422";
var myString = val.substr(val.indexOf("#") + 1)
alert(myString);
```